# Change Win10 Dsiplay language to English - does not work fully

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

I have a new Dektop with Win10 Pro in German (installed by the Computer Seller) which I need to be entirely in English for a non German speaking colleague of ours.

Now I have gone through the process of changing the display and input language to English and even have removed German completely.

Still parts of the interface remain to be in German. For example when I search for language in Start the system finds the German terms for the language Setting.

Can anyone advise whether there is a cure for this or do I really need to install the system in English anew?

Comment: If it’s a new install.  Why don’t you just reinstall Windows 10 using an English image?

Comment: 1.) I do not particular enjoy downloading and installing windows and want to make life as easy as possible & 2.) as per below it is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

seems that **only the initial admin user is affected by this shortcoming** described above.

When adding new users (either simple or admin users) the display language for those can be completely switched to a different display language without remaining breadcrumbs of the initial language.

New users start off in the default language but the changing to a different language works as it should.